# Reading Multi-Line Input From Command Line at once

Tags: java, input

I have a need for a simple class to read multi-line input at once.
For example, reading these two lines at once from a buffer:

> b8 b7
>
> g8 g2

This code only inputs the first line from the buffer, and without the first character...

```
int avail = System.in.read();
byte[] buf = new byte[avail];
System.in.read(buf);
String s = new String(buf);
String[] lines = s.split("\n");

//System.out.println(lines);
        
for(int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's without first char because the first char is saved in `avail` as a result of the first `read()` call. Then you are creating a buffer with size of the ASCII value of the first char (which is not the buffer size that you want).

Better approach is to read the input line by line with a `BufferedReader` like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                if ("".equals(line)) break;
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sb.toString().split("\n")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to enter empty line to exit this code. Is it possible to exit just after input done?

Comment: It will exit after the first empty line (just hit enter once more after you enter the last line of input)

Comment: Either you know exactly how many lines you want to read in advance (so you could know when the input is done) or you must signal the end of file somehow (CTRL+D or an empty line). Do you always want to read two lines of input?